# What is the best cleaning solution to prepare an outdoor fountain for fresh paint?

Tags: painting, outdoor

I have two outdoor fountains that we purchased about two years ago. They're in very good shape. But we never liked the color from the start. We now want to paint them the color we want. What is the best cleaner to help rid mineral deposits and bits of old algae from the surface of the fountains? They're painted concrete/resin with a matte finish. I don't care if what I use rubs away on the current finish since I'm repainting them. But will a solution of water and vinegar do? If so, what ratio is best? Or any other good suggestions for cleaning solutions[image]? I'm including a photo of the fountains so you know exactly what I'm working with.

Comment: I have found that phosphoric acid cleaners work best on lime/scale/mineral deposits, but hydrochloric acid products will also work (or your own dilute solution of water and muriatic/pool acid). Use care with these products because either will also etch concrete itself (though perhaps not *painted* concrete). Make sure that any existing unsound paint (that looks like it might peel) is sanded away prior to repainting. Use any paint that specifically says it is for in-water concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly standard pre-painting cleaner is Tri-Sodium Phosphate, (TSP) which is commonly available at paint stores. Scrub well with a stiff bristle brush and rinse.

If you have resistant deposits, muriatic acid (diluted - follow instructions, add acid to water and wear protective equipment/clothing) is a standard concrete etching solution before painting, and will dissolve hard-water "lime" buildup as well. But I'd not go there by default without giving a basic scrub with TSP a try first. I don't see any egregious lime buildup in the photo.